# Create a Variable that is declared for the length of a connection session?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I often test my SQL scripts in batches in a single script and have variable's declared at the beginning of the script to be used in multiple queries.

Is there a way to declare a variable that lasts, say, the length of the connection session so that I don't have to keep re-declaring/hard coding?

When testing queries individually, I either  run the entire script up until the variable declaration, temporarily re-declare the variable in the portion I'm testing, or temporarily hard code the variable.

```
Declare @StartDate as Date = '20220701'
Declare @EndDate as Date = '20220707'
```

Comment: No, that isn't how variables are defined. Variables only persist for the *batch* they were declared in and can only be referenced in that scope as well.

Comment: The most common approach I’ve seen is to have a variables table where you store key paired values and select from that table as needed.  Example table function, name, value, type.

Comment: @xQbert what I have assumed is that the solution should survive transaction rollback, which would be a problem if storing in a table.

Comment: If you commit the INSERTs they will survive rollback.  You can also use a #temp table which lives for the duration of the session.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Provided you're using SQL Server 2016+ you can make use of *session_context*.

This provides working storage for the lifetime of your session (`@@SPID`) for key/value data pairs.

```sql
/* set a value */
exec sp_set_session_context 'MyName', 'my value';
    
/* retrieve a value */
select Session_Context('MyName');
```

See the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-set-session-context-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) for details.

Comment: Even better than my old-school version. Thanks!

Comment: @TimLehner Probably like you I've used context_info years ago for some (dubious) reasons, fortunately MS improved the concept for 2016.

Comment: I wonder if MS improved it precisely because it's not always dubious to need scope outside of a transaction, especially since nested transactions don't really work the way most people think.

Comment: Completely agree, used session scope in various places eg in an ETL process to track SupplierId, errors, various static properties etc, works flawlessly; some schools of thought prefer to always pass and return values, just depends where you sit!

Answer (score 2):

One possibility that I've made use of is [`CONTEXT_INFO`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/context-info-transact-sql) which holds data for the duration of the session or batch, and survives transaction rollback.

```
declare @contextInfo varbinary(128) = cast('Things and Stuff' as varbinary(128));
set context_info @contextInfo;
select cast(context_info() as varchar(128));
```

Results:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Things and Stuff                                                                                                                

(1 row affected)
```